# How to use laravel shweshi/OpenGraph

Tags: laravel, facebook-opengraph

Here how to use it according to its GitHub

I already install the package:

Use Opengraph

`$data = OpenGraph::fetch("http://www.addemyplus.com/blogs/my-faith-for-your-love");`

that may return an array:

```
{"type":"website","title":"My Faith For Your Love","description":"","image":"http:\/\/www.addemyplus.com\/images\/frontend_images\/blogs\/medium\/57670.jpg"}
```

My problem is how can I use it on my blade that whenever I type a link in the form it will fetch the Og data of that site.

and show below the image and description

I have this code on form:

```
<form action="{{route('store_post_path')}}" method="POST">

    {{csrf_field()}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="title">title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Your Post Title or Question">
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="post">post</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="post_content" id="post_content" rows="3" placeholder="Briefly explain your question or Your Post Content"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="images" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="images-tab">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="custom-file">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="py-4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-toolbar justify-content-between">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Share your Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I use the code to fetch the Og property of the link? I want to view the image and title of the link below before submitting my post.. Please show some tutorial sites for this.

Answer (score 0):

Get the link from the form in post content. You can do it using regex.

```
function getUrl($string)
{
$regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $match);
return ($match);
}
$url = getUrl($string)
```

If there are any links in post content you will get array of links.

Use OpenGraph::fetch($url) to fetch the OG data of the url. That you can show in the view.